# How to get scores from BernoulliRBM

Tags: python, scikit-learn, neural-network, pca, rbm

I am trying to use [sklearn.neural_network.BernoulliRBM](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neural_network.BernoulliRBM.html) with iris dataset:

```
from sklearn import datasets
iris = datasets.load_iris() 
collist = ['SL', 'SW', 'PL', 'PW']
dat = pd.DataFrame(data=iris.data, columns=collist)

from sklearn.neural_network import BernoulliRBM
model = BernoulliRBM(n_components=2)
scores = model.fit_transform(dat)
print(scores.shape)
print(scores)
```

However, I am only getting 1 as output for all rows:

```
(150, 2)
[[1. 1.]
 [1. 1.]
 [1. 1.]
 [1. 1.]
 [1. 1.]  # same for all rows
```

Can I get values similar to scores for individual rows as I can get in principal component analysis? Else how can I get some useful numbers from RBM? I tried `model.score_samples(dat)` but that also gives value of `0` for vast majority of rows.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/neural_networks_unsupervised.html#rbm):

> The model makes assumptions regarding the distribution of inputs. At
>   the moment, scikit-learn only provides BernoulliRBM, which assumes the
>   inputs are either binary values or values between 0 and 1, each
>   encoding the probability that the specific feature would be turned on.

Since your `dat` values are all greater than 1, I'm guessing the model is truncating all input data to 1.0.  If, for example, you apply a normalization:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import normalize
scores = model.fit_transform(normalize(dat))
```

You'll get values with some variation:

```
array([[0.23041219, 0.23019722],
   [0.23046652, 0.23025144],
   ...,
   [0.23159369, 0.23137678],
   [0.2316786 , 0.23146158]])
```

Since your input features must have an interpretation as probabilities, you'll want to think about what if any normalization is reasonable for the particular problem you are solving.

Comment: It works, but it is not able to separate 3 species of iris dataset. What does this mean?

Comment: I think it fails to separate because your features, even when normalized, don't represent probabilities.  You can try other normalization strategies but I suspect this model (at least as implemented in sklearn) isn't a good choice for representing continuous features (length, width, etc.).

Comment: What is the main situation where BernoulliRBM is especially helpful?

Comment: When your features have a natural scaling into 0-1 range.  Some examples are image classification and bag of words text models.  http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/neural_networks/plot_rbm_logistic_classification.html